# Update single package from composer.json

Tags: kubernetes, composer-php

```
    {
    "require" : {
        "kubernetes/php-client" : "~1.20",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock" : "4.3.1",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer" : "6.8.0",
        "league/oauth2-google" : "4.0.0",
        "league/oauth2-client" : "2.6.1",
    }
}
```

I have this composer.json and i'm trying to update only the kubernetes/php-client, how can I do it? I tried with `composer update kubernetes/php-client` but I got `Cannot update only a partial set of packages without a lock file present. Run composer update to generate a lock file` .Tried `composer update` and got `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`, same with `composer install`. What should I do?

Comment: "without a lock file present" - that sounds like you are missing that file. Without it, there's no way that Composer can detect the current state of the other packages. Please share more details about this. Also, if you know which package version you want to use, just put it in the file like the other versions

Comment: Actually this information could be inside the vendor folder if the installation set is still complete. But then I guess Composer would have tried that, too. Anyway, I'd first of all backup the vendor folder (if not the complete project) and then would suggest to dig in there as otherwise like @NicoHaase commented, the lock file is currently missing but necessary for Composer to keep things aligned here.

Answer (score 0):

For `composer.json` I recommend you to not be too specific with the versions of the dependencies. Please stick with minor version (e.g. `6.8.*`) or even major version (e.g. `6.*`) unless if really necessary or recommended by the dependencies' vendors.

This will provide some leeway to composer to compute the best combination of the dependencies' versions based on the latest versions available in the repository. Otherwise, it would be like your case where Composer failed to find a matching combination.

You can refer [Composer's guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints) for all the available syntaxes for defining version constraints.

Once you have fixed your `composer.json`, you can retry running `composer update` to generate the required `composer.lock`.